# Showing related fields in datagridview for EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an EntityFramework application with a binding to a data grid view.

```
dgvEvents.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvEvents.DataSource = context.Events.ToList();
```

This binds to Events, which works fine. Events has two related entities - Users and Doors. How can I show the users full name field (Users.FullName) in a datagridview that is bound to Events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by -

```
        dgvEvents.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvEvents.DataSource = context.Events.ToList();

        int row = 0;

        foreach (Event e in (List<Event>)context.Events.ToList())
        {
            string doorName = e.Door.DoorName;
            string userName = e.User.FullName;

            dgvEvents.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value = doorName;
            dgvEvents.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value = userName;

            row++;
        }
```